# Replace inverter manual potentiometer with mcp41010

Tags: arduino, digital-potentiometer

I have an 3 phase ac inverter that uses standard potentiometer for motor speed regulation. 
[image]

The speed reference voltage is 0-10v and i need to control it using arduino. In MCP41010 datasheet I couldn't find the maximum voltage between the potentiometer pins only the supply voltage. Has anyone got experience with this digital potentiometer and if it's possible to be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit sneaky, but it's there (Section 1.0 Electrical Characteristics):

> **Resistor Terminals**
>   Voltage Range \$V_{A,B,W}\$: Min 0, Max \$V_{DD}\$

Doesn't seem like it's appropriate for your application.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad it was the only available pot i could find here, I'll probably wait a month to get compatible one from ebay